# "Assignment to undeclared variable" error in third party library when using Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

Since Create React App seems to be dying, recently I've tried to migrate one of our projects to Vite. Unfortunately I've met an obstacle I don't know how to deal with.

The project seems to be starting just fine, but in runtime, when I open the page, I get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable cptable
    make_xlsx xlsx.js:10
```

I looked into the aforementioned file in `node_modules` and indeed there is such assignment there:

```
//no code is omitted here, there is no declaration of cptable
var XLSX = {};
(function make_xlsx(XLSX){
XLSX.version = '0.8.20';
var current_codepage = 1200, current_cptable;
if(typeof module !== "undefined" && typeof require !== 'undefined') {
    if(typeof cptable === 'undefined') cptable = require('./dist/cpexcel');
    current_cptable = cptable[current_codepage];
}
//the rest is omitted
```

This comes from `tempa-xlsx`, a dependency of `react-data-export`, a package which we directly use. The NPM page of `react-data-export` states they are working on a new version of this library, but I don't know when they are going to release it ("soon", they state). Besides, the is no guarantee this is the only case within our project, so I'd like to learn a way to deal with this kind of issue somehow.

My config of Vite is very simple so far: I only add two plugins, `@vitejs/plugin-react` and `vite-jsconfig-paths`.

To my understanding, indirect cause of this error is so called *strict mode* in which you can't use undeclared variables. This is, overall, a good feature to use, but I'd rather turn it off for external sources I don't have control over anyway - is there any way to achieve this?

Theoretically I could fix the code of the library and hotwire it but it would be an act of desperation, I'd rather not do that.

What are my options?